# Find all combinations that sum up to a specific number

Tags: combinatorics

How to find all the combinations that adds up to a certain number, given the number of elements?

For example if target $T$ is $ 100 $ and number of elements is $2$.
Then the result is $101$. ($100+  0$, $99 + 1$, $98 + 2$,… $1 + 99$, $0+ 100$.)

What would the formula be, if the given number of elements is $ 3, 4$, etc?

Comment: lookup "stars and bars" method

Comment: @Vasya  Comment upvoted, that seems to perfectly fit the use case of the question that the OP has posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more general way to do this is to use generating functions. The number of ways to write $100$ as the sum of two non-negative integers is the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in the product
$$
(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{100})(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{100})
$$
and the number of ways to write $100$ as the sum of $5$ non-negative integers is the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in 
$$
(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{100})^{5}.
$$

This method is more flexible because you can control which terms appear in the sum. For example, if you want the first term to be even, the second term to be a multiple of $4$, and the third term to be a multiple of $6$, you want the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in
$$
(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \cdots + x^{100})(1 + x^4 + x^8 + \cdots + x^{100})(1 + x^6 + x^{12} + \cdots + x^{96}).
$$

Comment: What is x here?

Comment: $x$ is a placeholder. When you use generating functions, you don’t substitute values into $x$, you just read the coefficients. The polynomial multiplication takes care of “all possible ways” to combine terms from the different polynomials that were multiplied.

Comment: great answer but just to note I don't think this counts all the combinations only , I think it counts all subsets of the cartesian product $[0,100] \times [0,100]$ that sum to $100$

Answer (score 3):

The method you're looking for is called [Stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

The formula is
$$N=\binom{n+k-1}{n}$$
where $n$ is the number you want to split and $k$ is the number of parts.

Comment: should be N = $n+k-1 \choose k-1$ ?

Comment: @Cheng it's the same.